# Update value in Grid

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid that has some date values. What I like to do is to convert those date values into UTC date format and then enter that inside the table.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KruSQL %>"  

    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[Microbiology] SET RoomNum=@RoomNum, CollDate=@CollDate, WaterFixure=@WaterFixure Where ID=@ID">
    <UpdateParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="RoomNum" Type="String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="WaterFixure" Type="String" />            
      <asp:Parameter Name="CollDate" Type="DateTime" />             
    </UpdateParameters>
```

My qustion is how can I make use of :

```
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[Microbiology] SET RoomNum=@RoomNum, CollDate=@CollDate, WaterFixure=@WaterFixure Where ID=@ID"
```

and still update the value of CollDate to UTC. Is there anyway to do this in the code behind and still make us of the UpdateCommand

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[Microbiology] SET RoomNum=@RoomNum, CollDate=DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @ColDate), WaterFixure=@WaterFixure Where ID=@ID"
```

convert Date to UTCDate :

```
DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), YOUR_DATE)
```

Comment: Yes but not sure if this takes into account daytime savings

Comment: you can try this, and test it.